# PHAsset (get photos without options)

Tags: ios, objective-c, phasset

In what order I will get photos if I make query without options (set nil). Will be chaos or exists default order??

for example: `photos = [PHAsset fetchAssetsInAssetCollection:_assetCollection options:nil];`

Comment: According to the doc, `Options that specify a filter predicate and sort order for the fetched assets, or nil to use default options. For details, see PHFetchOptions.`. "Default options" is not specified, but it could change with iOS versions.

Comment: I read it, but I need know what a "default options"